# Printing out Visual Studio PowerShell variables

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Is there a simple way to print out the VS variables like.

```
$(SolutionDir)
$(TargetDir)
$(MSBuildProjectDir) 
$(PacketOutputDir) 
ect
```

I know I could look up what each one does, and induce their value from there, but is there something I can type in the Package Manager Console or something to just get what the current value of it is?  Or an easy way to Output them to the output?

Trying to configure my nuget.targets file and I think I'm putting something in the wrong place, finding these values on the fly would be very helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, those are not variables that are directly exposed to PowerShell - I think Visual Studio substitutes them on the fly when needed (like the pre and post build steps). They are referred to as macros in the UI as well.

You can view their values a couple of different ways. You may have some luck with the [NuGetPSVariables](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetPSVariables) package - it contains scripts that log the values for the variables in the init, install and uninstall nuget scripts (if you are building a nuget package). The uninstall script definitely expects that the script start with a params declaration to capture the `$installPath, $toolsPath, $package and $project` variables.

You can also view the values of those macros by looking at the project properties, build tab and clicking on the Edit Pre-Build button. At the bottom of the dialog box that opens it will show you the current values and all the available variables:

[image: Visual Studio Pre/Post Build Macros Dialog]

This page has quite a bit of information on how to package things up. Hopefully it can shed some additional light on what might be missing: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package